# Does a company need to follow some methodology (e.g. Scrum) to be PCI DSS compliant?

Tags: pci-dss

Does a company need to follow some development methodology (e.g. Scrum) and keep records of the development process (e.g. spring backlogs, product backlogs) to be compliant?

Can it become compliant with only bug- and vulnerability-fixing documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: Not a QSA, just have some PCI experience

The Requirement you are interested in is 6 - "Develop and maintain secure systems and applications"

The short answer is no - you cannot be compliant with just documentation of vulnerability and bug fixing.  You must document policies for (probably not a complete list) :

- vulnerability finding procedures
- vulnerability assessing procedures
- vulnerability information assessing (ie, who do you trust about vulnerabilities)
- third party patching - ie, that you apply security patches in an appropriate timeframe
- that you have "industry-standard" development processes (this isn't prescriptive as to what you need, but you must demonstrate you have a standard that is at least as informative as scrum or the pmbok or kanban or what have you)
- that information security is included throughout the lifecycle (basically, you are worrying about security at design time, at implementation time, at testing time, at rollout time and during maintenance/operation of the software)
- that all these processes and policies are written down and known by all developers
- that you have policy to prevent dev accounts and data from reaching prod
- that you have policy to ensure that one person can't write and promote the code (must have two sets of eyes on every change)
- that you have policy ensuring that code review checks that all code meets secure coding guidelines
- that management examines code review artifacts and signs off that appropriate review was done
- that dev and test environments are different than production, with separate access controls
- that controlled information from production isn't used in development
- that software change controls are robust and documented
- that changes are reversible
- that all developers understand/have been trained on the OWASP Top Ten mitigations and other standard secure code techniques / information
- that you scan public facing web applications regularly with scanning software

Wow. That got longer than I expected.

tldr; no - you need to do much more than document your bug and vulnerability fixing.

Comment: Nice answer!  I would add that the developers must not only know the defined practices; the QSA is responsible for performing developer interviews to confirm that they are being followed.

Comment: Note that this is only needed if your own software actually touches the card data, and it may (depending on your exact setup) be easier to re-architect so that third parties handle all the card data, and your own software never sees it (except perhaps encrypted with keys that you don't have access to).

Comment: @MikeScott Agree, from a DSS point of view, though I'll note that most of the above is just good security practice in general.  If your organization is of any size and doing public facing anything, it probably ought to be doing most of DSS Req 6 anyways, even if it doesn't call it PCI compliance.